# How to Acces nested Json Array data in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, api

I was trying to extract data from JSON in Java.

[image]

have any idea about how to access these JSON data which is underlined in blue it is nested JSON array I guess? I know about JSON object and getstring(key) but it is working only for these data which is underlined in red. I want that blueline data. Any solution would be great. Any help would be useful for me I am working on this issue for the last 5 days.
**Java Code**

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
```

response is a string which contain json data.

```
{
    "calories":115,
    "totalWeight":223.0,
    "dietLabels":["LOW_FAT"],
    "healthLabels":["VEGAN","VEGETARIAN","PEANUT_FREE","TREE_NUT_FREE","ALCOHOL_FREE","SULPHITE_FREE"],
    "cautions":["SULFITES"],
    "totalNutrients":{
        "ENERC_KCAL": {"label":"Energy","quantity":115.96,"unit":"kcal"},
        "FAT":{"label":"Fat","quantity":0.37910000000000005,"unit":"g"},
        "FASAT":{"label":"Saturated","quantity":0.06244,"unit":"g"},
        "FAMS":{"label":"Monounsaturated","quantity":0.01561,"unit":"g"},
        "FAPU":{"label":"Polyunsaturated","quantity":0.11373,"unit":"g"},
        "CHOCDF":{"label":"Carbs","quantity":30.796300000000002,"unit":"g"},
        "FIBTG":{"label":"Fiber","quantity":5.351999999999999,"unit":"g"},
        "SUGAR":{"label":"Sugars","quantity":23.169700000000002,"unit":"g"},
        "PROCNT":{"label":"Protein","quantity":0.5798,"unit":"g"},
        "CHOLE":{"label":"Cholesterol","quantity":0.0,"unit":"mg"}
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add a simplified version of your json here. in Text

Comment: I've Added JSON data @kelvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
JSONArray dietLabels = jo.getJSONArray("dietLabels");
```

To access ENERC_KCAL Data you can do something like that :

```
JSONObject totalNutrients = jo.getJSONObject("totalNutrients");
JSONObject ENERC_KCAL = totalNutrients.getJSONObject("ENERC_KCAL");
```

on the JsonObject where jo is the main json object (from the given json string) and "dietLabels" is the name of the array.

Comment: i've added some changes in question and i want to access 'totalNutrients' also.